# Dividir valores entre años de una misma columna en Oracle

Tags: oracle

Tengo el siguiente `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(FEC_INFO) AS Anio,
    SUM(MON_ACTIVOS_TOTALES) AS Activos_Totales
FROM
    ACTIVOS_TOTALES
WHERE
    YEAR(FEC_INFO) BETWEEN YEAR(pFecInicial) AND YEAR(pFecFinal)
GROUP BY
    YEAR(FEC_INFO)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(FEC_INFO) DESC
```

> **Nota:** `pFecInicial` y `pFecFinal` son variables `IN` que contienen el rango de fechas indicado por el usuario en la página web.

Retorna lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito una columna más `"DIF_PORCENTUAL"`, que almacene el porcentaje de la diferencia entre los años, por ejemplo necesito que el resultado quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde para sacar el porcentaje de cada año sería así:

> **Para el 2017**: 2737006401.63 / 2320472647.37 = 1.17950384148337
>
> **Para el 2016**: 2320472647.37 / 1227218765.97 = 1.890838627729007
>
> **Para el 2015**: NULL porque no hay año 2014

No sé cómo sacar ésa última columna, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sirve, logré resolver el problema utilizando la función analítica `LAG`. Acá Les dejo el script final resuelto:

```
SELECT
    Anio,
    Activo_Total,
    (CASE WHEN Activo_Total_Anterior > 0 THEN
        Activo_Total / Activo_Total_Anterior
    ELSE
        NULL
    END) AS DIF_PORCENTUAL
FROM
    (SELECT
        YEAR(FEC_INFO) AS Anio,
        SUM(MON_ACTIVOS_TOTALES) AS Activo_Total,
        LAG(SUM(MON_ACTIVOS_TOTALES), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(FEC_INFO)) AS Activo_Total_Anterior
    FROM
        ACTIVOS_TOTALES
    WHERE
        YEAR(FEC_INFO) BETWEEN YEAR(:pFecInicial) AND YEAR(:pFecFinal)
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(FEC_INFO)
    )
    ORDER BY
        Anio DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que esto te podría servir

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  YEAR(FEC_INFO) AS Anio,
        SUM(MON_ACTIVOS_TOTALES) AS Activos_Totales
        FROM    ACTIVOS_TOTALES
        WHERE   YEAR(FEC_INFO) BETWEEN YEAR(pFecInicial) AND YEAR(pFecFinal)
        GROUP BY YEAR(FEC_INFO)
)
SELECT  T1.Anio,
    T1.Activos_Totales,
    T1.Activos_Totales / T2.Activos_Totales AS DIF_PORCENTUAL
    FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T2.Anio = T1.Anio
    ORDER BY T1.Anio;
```

Usamos una ["Common table expresion"](http://www.morganslibrary.com/reference/with.html) a partir de tu consulta, y la usamos de forma recursiva para que con cada fila, obtengamos el valor de `Activos_Totales`del año anterior y así poder calcular `DIF_PORCENTUAL`

Comment: Gracias pero logré resolverlo un poco más fácil.

Comment: @AlonsoFallas, estupendo.